# Complex regex sed replacement not working but not throwing errors

Tags: centos, sed, regular-expression

I am working in CentOS 7 trying to do find / sed one liners to fix a ton of files. Specifically two in a row:

1. First, to add "ignoreOlderThan = 14d" immediately after every `[monitor://...]` (working)
2. Second, to find a `[monitor://...]` group that has two "ignoreOlderThan" and remove the last occurrence.

I have several hundred files that look similar to this (this is the current test file I'm using):

```
[default]
host = 10.2.2.15

[monitor://apath]
ignoreOlderThan = 14d
index=test
sourcetype=whatever
ignoreOlderThan = 30d

[monitor://truck]
ignoreOlderThan = 14d

[monitor://apath]
ignoreOlderThan = 14d
index=test
sourcetype=whatever
ignoreOlderThan = 30d
```

The first full command I use is:

```
find -name inputs.conf -exec sed -ie 's/\(\[monitor:.*\]\)/\1\nignoreOlderThan = 14d/g' {} +
```

This one works. It adds `ignoreOlderThan = 14d` immediately below a `[monitor://...]`.

The second, more complex one, does not work:

```
find -name inputs.conf -exec sed -ie 's/\(\[monitor[^\]]+\][^\[]?\)\(ignoreOlderThan\s?=\s?[0-9]+\w\)\([^\[]+?ignoreOlderThan\s?=\s?[0-9]+\w\)\([^\[]+\)?/\1\3\4/g' {} +
```

I've tested several possible scenarios using regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/okCSfl/6

https://regex101.com/r/okCSfl/7

https://regex101.com/r/okCSfl/8

https://regex101.com/r/okCSfl/9

The regex works, so I think the issue is somewhere in the sed command, where I'm a lot weaker. I've escaped the parenthesis as needed for capture groups and the command runs... but it doesn't do anything. I thought it may be because sometimes the 4th capture group doesn't exist, but I've also tested a file where every group would have all 4.

I also read that some sed interprets everything as one line, which is why some of my test cases have no spaces at all between newlines.

---

Edit: @choroba pointed out that sed does one line at a time and suggested perl and gave an example. I played around a little and got it working with the following:

`find -name inputs.conf -exec perl -0777 -pi -e 's/(\[monitor:[^[]+?)^(ignoreOlderThan\s?=\s?[0-9]+\w)([^[]+?^ignoreOlderThan\s?=\s?[0-9]+\w[^[]+)/$1$3/gms' {} +`

Demonstrated here:

https://regex101.com/r/okCSfl/10

Comment: sed processes the input line by line. Its regex can't easily match multiple lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed processes the input line by line. Its regex can't easily match multiple lines.

Perl, on the other hand, can read the whole file when the option `-0777` is specified:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^(\[monitor:[^[]+^ignoreOlderThan .*)^ignoreOlderThan = \w+/$1/gms' input > output
```

- `-0777` slurps the whole file
- `-p` prints the input after processing it
- `/g` repeats the substitution
- `/s` makes `.` match a newline (which it normally doesn't)
- `/m` makes `^` match at the beginning of each newline, not just the whole string (and similarly for `$` but we don't need it here)

Comment: Interesting, that's good to know. How would you integrate this into the find portion? I know nothing about perl. The regex looks much different than what I was using. Does $1 equate to \1 in my sed?

Comment: You can integrate it similarly to sed. Also, I tried a simple regex, but feel free to try anything else you like. `$1` is the first matching group, `\1` only works in the pattern itself, e.g. `s/(.)\1/$1/`.

Comment: find -name inputs.conf -exec perl -0777 -pi -e 's/(\[monitor:[^[]+?)^(ignoreOlderThan\s?=\s?[0-9]+\w)([^[]+?^ignoreOlderThan\s?=\s?[0-9]+\w[^[]+)/$1$3/gms' {} +

This is what I ended up with